# Discrete random variables are equal

Tags: probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

We have continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$. Our goal is to find the distribution of $X$, such that for any suitable function $g$, the distributions $g(X)$ and $Y$ have the same distribution. We could solve
$$E(\phi(g(X)))=\int \phi(g(x))f_X(x)dx = \int \phi(y)f_Y(y)dy=E(\phi(Y))$$ 
for $f_X$ with $\phi$ being an arbitrary suitable function. Substitution $g(x)=y$ gives us that the pdf of $X$ is
$$f_X(x)=f_Y(g(x))|g'(x)|.$$
The question is, what if $X$ and $Y$ are discrete? What would be the alternative to the change of variable to find the pmf of $X$? Could we use the same approach or is it fundamentally a different problem?

Comment: I have no idea what you wrote. Can you be more specific about the quantifiers? What is $X$?

Comment: What does “any suitable function “ mean and how do your first set of equations relate to your first paragraph?

Comment: I do observe that if you allow $g(x)=0$ and $h(x)=1$ (for all $x$) to both be “suitable functions” then there is no random variable $X$ for which $g(X)$ and $h(X)$ have the same distribution.

Comment: Please see change of variable theorem (see Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis for example) if you wish to focus on the specific properties of the function $g$. It has to be bijective, differentiable, open domain, measureable etc. I decided not to specify them, as it is not the important part in this problem.

Comment: One wonders when you will specify the important part of this problem.

Comment: @Scippy From the comments its quite clear your way of describing the question is not at all clear. So why don't you help us a bit by giving us an example in the continuous case, regarding whatever you want ? (by editing the question)

Comment: Fix $Y$ as a random variable. Contrary to the goals of the first paragraph of this question, there is no random variable $X$ such that any two (differentiable and bijective) functions of $X$ have the same distribution as $Y$.  For any candidate $X$, just take $g_1(X)=X$ and $g_2(X)=X+1$; obviously $g_1(X)$ and $g_2(X)$ cannot have the same distribution. [So, the goals of this question are impossible, even when "suitable function" is interpreted as in the previous Scippy comment to mean "differentiable and bijective."]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to answer one interpretation of your question. This should at least be useful to clarify your requirements. Let $Y$ be a discrete random variable with range $y_1,\ldots,y_m$ and $P(Y=y_j)=p_j$, where $p_j>0.$ Let $g$ be the "suitable function". For consistency you need $X=g^{-1}(Y)$.

Now define for each $y_j$ $n_j$ disjoint sets $x_{i,j}$ inside the domain of $g$ such that:
$$ \bigcup_{i \leq n_j} x_{i,j}=g^{-1}(y_j).$$
Next choose any set of positive numbers $q_{i,j}$ with
$$ \sum_{i\leq n_j} q_{i,j}=p_j \text{ for all } j=1\ldots, m.$$

Each $q_{i,j}$ defines the mass of the component $x_{i,j}$, i.e. $P(x_{i,j})=q_{i,j}$ and you can distribute the mass within each $x_{i,j}$ as you wish.

Following this recipe ensures:
$$ P(g(X)=y_j)=P(X=g^{-1}(y_j))=P(\bigcup_{i \leq n_j} x_{i,j})=\sum_{i\leq n_j} P(x_{i,j})=p_j.$$